# The type definition of Plotly.animate not found

Tags: typescript, plotly.js

I am using plotly.js in Vue@3.2.38 project with Typescript@4.5.5, which I installed by following command:

```
npm install plotly.js-dist-min
npm install @types/plotly.js-dist-min
```

I write codes in Visual Studio Code with Volar extension.

When I use animate function (https://plotly.com/javascript/animations/), VSCode threw the ts(2339) warning at

```
Plotly.animate()
       ^^^^^^^^
```

which is saying

> "Property 'animate' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/WORKSPACE-PATH/node_modules/@types/plotly.js/index")'"

Does it mean that @types/plotly.js-dist-min doesn't include the type of "animate" function?

And how to fix it?

Please excuse my poor English. Thank you.

#### dir

```
dist/
node_modules/
  - @types/
     - plotly.js/
        - lib/
        - index.d.ts
        - LICENSE
        - package.json
        - README.md
     - plotly.js-dist-min/
        - index.d.ts
        - LICENSE
        - package.json
        - README.md
    - others
  - plotly.js-dist-min
     - LICENSE
     - package.json
     - plotly.min.js
     - README.md
  - others
public/
  - index.html
src/
  - others
.eslintrc.js
.gitignore
babel.config.js
package-lock.json
package.json
README.md
tsconfig.json
vue.config.js
```

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: The [source](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/plotly.js-dist-min/index.d.ts) of the typings is literally the typings of `plotly.js`, so my guess is you need to install `@types/plotly.js` as well.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but installing `@types/plotly.js` additionally is not working for me.

Comment: Can we see your TSConfig and folder structure?

Comment: OK, information added to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @types definition is either not complete or not up to date. I also stumbled upon some missing types.

As of today:

```
"@types/plotly.js": "2.12.1",
"plotly.js-basic-dist": "2.16.1",
```

Somebody needs to contribute to the opensource project.

Comment: Thank you for your useful suggestions.
I did not know that the type implementation was incomplete.
I will submit a pull request in the future if possible :)